# Get all rows excluding a column jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to read all the rows of a table.

Now, I want to exclude a particular a column which has class "exclude" while finding all the tr.

```
var rows = $("#" + myTableId).find("tr");
```

Comment: Where is the exclude class: on the header cell or on all cells bolonging to the column?

Comment: Just `"#" + myTableId + " tr:not(.exclude)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table structure is how I imagined it, then you can do it this way:

Iterate over rows and create replica rows without `exclude` column.

```js
$(function() {
  var rows = [];
  $("#table").clone().find("tr").each(function() {
    var $row = $("<tr>");
    $(this).find("td").not(".exclude").each(function() {
      $row.append($(this));
    });
    rows.push($row);
  });
  console.log(rows);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<tr><td>1</td><td>11</td><td class="exclude">111</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td class="exclude">22</td><td>222</td></tr>
<tr><td class="exclude">3</td><td>33</td><td>333</td></tr>
</table>
```

If you need a shorter solution:

It has many assumptions related to it, but I guess it should work fine for you:

```js
$(function() {
  var $table = $("#table").clone();
  $table.find(".exclude").remove();
  var rows = $table.find("tr");
  
  console.log(rows);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
<tr><td>1</td><td>11</td><td class="exclude">111</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td class="exclude">22</td><td>222</td></tr>
<tr><td class="exclude">3</td><td>33</td><td>333</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this solution , But i do not want to iterate. Is there any other way to do this in single line.

Comment: I can't think of other ways. A row has cells, and if you take a row, *you get all the cells too*. The only way to "take the row" but "with only some cells" is to create duplicate or dummy rows and then add copies of the cells that you want. Which is what this answer is doing. You can't even put the original cells in the dummy rows because that would remove the cells from the original rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .not() function (http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude matching elements:

```
$( "tr" ).not( ".exclude" );
```

This will select all `<tr>` elements that do not have the exclude class.

Comment: I want to load the tr but not that column.

Comment: Not sure how possible that is. But my example should help get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care so much for the rows (`<tr>`) and more for the cells (`<td>`), then you can gather the cells in a simple array of 2 levels deep, as below. The first level of the array acts as the rows, the next level contains the cells (those that match the filter).

The advantage is that you have access to the original cells, not duplicated cells in duplicated rows, so if you need to manipulate the cells (e.g. change their content or their css) then you can do so with ease.

```js
var rows = [];
$("#table tr").each(function(index, row) {
  rows.push($(row).find("td").not(".exclude"));
});

// What follows next is just to show the result

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  console.log("rows[" + i + "] --> " + GetCellInfo(rows[i]));
}

function GetCellInfo(cells) {
  var str = "|";
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    str += " " + cells[i].innerText + " |";
  }
  return str;
}
```

```css
#table td {
  background: #ddd
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td class="exclude">XX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="exclude">XX</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="exclude">XX</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```